# How can I get the Spotify Android API to queue a set of songs

Tags: java, android, media, spotify

So I have an app that uses the official "Android Spotify SDK" and I can't get the String ArrayList of track ids to queue after I play the first one in the array. I can get the first one to play, but that's an individual song, I want a list.

So I did the spotifyPlayer.queue(operationCallback: null, *trackUriList.get(loopint)*) and it stops playback all together. I checked the uris and they are valid, and even display to log properly. Anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: I'm doing something like this:
`mPlayer.playUri(null, playlinkFinalList.get(0),0,0);
mPlayer.queue(null,playlinkFinalList.get(1));`

where playlinkFinalList is the String ArrayList and mPlayer is the SpotifyPlayer object.
`mPlayer.skipToNext(null);`

Comment: I try `skipToNext(null)` and it ends playback all together. My URIs are formed properly too. I ran a logcat and printed the URIs before putting them into `playUri` or `queue` and no dice. I thought maybe doing `queue()` then doing `resume` without any `playURI` would just play the list, but nope